# Installing pretrained ML models on AWS opensearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch, amazon-opensearch, semantic-search

In a local opensearch setup, I see we can register huggingface models using an API (https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/neural-search/). I am wondering if we can do the same with an AWS-managed opensearch. Say I want to install a huggingface model, how should I do that? All I got from reading the documentation is Amazon Sage Maker, which I believe is not free. I am using opensearch 2.9.